# How to 'p4 add' only new files from a directory

Tags: perforce

```
find . -type f -print | p4 -x - add
```

This adds all files from `$PWD` and its sub directories, but it prints the message `can't add existing file` for files already in perforce.

How do I add only new files which are not in P4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Perforce [versions 12.1](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/reconcile.html) and above, you can use the command `p4 reconcile`, which will reconcile any added, deleted, or edited files outside of Perforce.  To use it specifically to add files, type `p4 reconcile -a`.

Just a note though, it doesn't do any harm to do the command you are doing.  It issues a warning for any files already existing, but that's it.  It will still add the files that don't currently exist in Perforce.  Your command is the way I have done it until the `p4 reconcile` command was created.